# How to split log file using Selenium with Django

Tags: django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, logging

My system already has a log file and log system error to "errors.log"

When I implement Selenium to my Django project, I have got issue with Selenium log file because Selenium log was override my System log
I had try many way such like add Selenium webdriver log path :

```py
webdriver.Chrome(ConstTest.CHROME_DRIVER_WINDOWS_PATH, options=options,
                                    service_log_path=ConstTest.TEST_LOG_PATH)
```

and change my System log path

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': LOGS_DIR + '/logs.log',      *changed*
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'encoding': 'utf-8',
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['default'],
        'level': logging.DEBUG
    }
}
```

But It still override my log, How can I separate my log file from System with log file in Selenium ?